# Is any Microsoft Graph API available for backup exchange email O365 service

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Is any Graph API/SDK available to take backup of O365 service exchange email for multiple tenants.
I am new in Microsoft Graph API, any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you looked into this yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview It seems like backup is not part of Graph API. See this and find backup and restore for exchange: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-server-development#exchange-developer-content

Comment: If you're talking about Microsoft Graph API, backup/archive related APIs not exposed till the point. Consider filing a [feature request with Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform), so that that they consider implementing it. For time being, as updated by @AndyRefuerzo try either MAPI/Exchange Web services APis to build your backup/archive solutions.

Comment: Upvote this feature-request [techcommunity.microsoft.com..](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/provide-a-message-import-feature/idc-p/3984709#M2105)